# r - Different impacts of xlim() on geom_point and geom_histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I overlaid a scatter plot with a histogram and then use `xlim()` to set x axis. But it seems `xlim()` removes 1 and 10 for the histogram but has no effect on scatter plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

(d <- data.frame(key = 1:10, value = 1:10))

# xlim() seems to not include 1 and 10 for the histogram
ggplot(data = d, aes(x = value)) + 
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) +
    geom_point(data = d, aes(x = key, y = value)) +
    xlim(1, 10)
```

The version of ggplot2 used here is 2.2.1

Comment: It seems currently I do not have the privilege to edit the post due to relatively low reputation. Sorry. :) @LJW

Comment: You always have permission to edit your own posts.